# Select rows from table with tag a or b and c

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I have a table with objects, a table with tags and a linking table.

The statement without the second condition works, but the out commented one yields no results, this probably because `objects_tags.id_tag` cannot be two different numbers at the same time.

```
SELECT objects.id
    FROM objects
    JOIN objects_tags ON objects.id = objects_tags.id_object
    JOIN tags ON tags.id = objects_tags.id_tag
WHERE objects_tags.id_ IN (3,4);
#WHERE (objects_tags.id_tag IN (3,4)) AND (objects_tags.id_tag = 6);
```

**Is there a way to select all the entries in `objects` which are linked to `tags` with ID 3 or 4 and 6?**

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Simplify if possible ([mcve].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT ot.id_object
FROM objects_tags ot 
GROUP BY ot.id_object
HAVING SUM(ot.id_ IN (3, 4)) > 0 AND   -- has either 3 or 4
       SUM(ot.id_tag = 6) > 0;         -- also has 6
```

Note that you only need the `object_tags` table for this query, because the query is only using ids.  If you want additional information, then `join`s may be necessary.